# Printing: wrong number of copies (N square copies)

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I just upgraded to 18.04LTS, I print over a network printer using CUPS. 
Since my upgrade, when printing N copies of a PDF (through Okular or Evince), I get N^2 copies printed. However, when I use a direct call to CUPS: `lp -d my-printer -n 5 example.pdf` I get the right number of copies (5 in this example).
I guess the applications are simply calling N times N copies.

Moreover, the printing options (stapling, etc.) are absent from the Options panel, and I need to tune them through the general Setting panel of Ubuntu.

What is the communication channel between applications and CUPS? How can I configure my printing "pipeline" so that it directly calls something like the `lp` cmmand?

Thanks for your help!

Note: this is not the same situation as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265538/cups-prints-n%C2%B2-as-many-copies-as-i-want since in their case, the lp command was giving also the wrong number of copies.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a result of the Okular bug [Okular, when printing 2 pages per sheet, prints the wrong pages.](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=402779) which says:

> If I try and print two pages from a PDF (a Canon camera manual in this instance), two per A4 sheet, I get four pages, the wrong ones, two per sheet.

As Nate Graham discusses it may be a lower-level Qt bug, which could possibly be [Printing multiple copies with WebEngine results in printing (number of copies) * (number of copies) copies.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56722) which was allegedly fixed in Qt 5.8 and 18.04 should have 5.9.5, so I'm not sure why it would persist, but it appears there is still a bug in Qt or in Okular.

Answer (score 2):

The purposes of this post: (1) suggest a workaround; (2) ask for bug-reporting advice. (I'm on plain Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, btw.)

**(1)** On my system, this bug still shows up, and it shows up as an **Evince** problem. Like OP, Evince gives me n<sup>2</sup> the number of copies of PDFs as I ask for. But...

- `lp -d my_printer -n 2 example.pdf` prints two copies;
- [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) prints the correct number of copies (ask for 2, get 2 printed); and
- [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) prints the correct number of copies (ask for 2, get 2 printed).

So using either qpdfview (which is in Ubuntu software sources) or Foxit will avoid the problem arising from Evince.

**(2)** Still, **ONLY** Evince will give me 4 copies if I ask for 2, and 9 copies if I ask for 3, etc.

There are bug-reports relating to this issue (or one presenting much like it) on other systems:

- [Debian #886892](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=886892)
- [Redhat #439937](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=439937)

but I can't find such an item in the [Evince bug-list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince). If anyone can point me to the bug reported there, great — otherwise, I should add this myself.

*Caveat lector*: I see that there is [meant to be a CUPS-based fix for this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188154/cups-prints-n%c2%b2-copies-when-collation-is-enabled#comment2002409_1188154) but for some reason `cups-filters` is still at 1.20.2 on my LTS system.